# Angularjs Tabs with CSP

Tags: jquery, angularjs, tabs, content-security-policy

Using CSP with Angularjs. Getting below error for all the screens which includes TABS (Angular Tabs).

Tabs are implemented like - https://codepen.io/jasoncluck/pen/iDcbh

**Chrome error** - refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following content security policy directive:  "default-src 'self' '....

**Firefox error** - the page's settings blocked the loading of a resource.

setting below in header

```
response.addheader(Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline')
```

Restriction is there for using 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' with default-src.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically it doesn't allow inline scripting check this link [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).                 So you can do some thing like - `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  http://your address">` OR you add `img-src*` in your meta tag - `http://your address'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src *">`

Comment: Thanks. I am not allowed to use -- script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  http://your address". Direct Tabs are working fine. But Tab within other Tab is not working. img-src * added .. No change from this. same error

Comment: If it works direct tabs and not within tabs seems surprising. Can you replicate somewhere online so that i can see the exact code.